# RSS2HTML (Feed For All)

Tags: php, javascript, html, rss, slider

I am working with this RSS2HTML and so far its amazing. The only problem with it is that it puts all it's data into a table :(   I want to put a slider on my website that slider through table data but I cannot seem to find a easy script for this. Does anyone know of a table data slider script? I just want it to slider left and right when the user clicks on arrows. Thanks!

This is the script I tried to edit. If you change all the "TR" to "UL" and "TD" to "LI" the script will work again. Trying to convert it to slide table data kills the script entirely :/

http://pastebin.com/ngShQQJm

Comment: Please add more detail about what you have at the moment (which RSS2HTML are you referring to?), what the markup looks like and what exactly the slider looks like that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net).

Adding the features is as simple as:

```
$('table').dataTable();
```

Make sure the table is properly formatted HTML (uses thead, tbody) and has an ID.  If not, you'll have to do some crawling through to add those.

Datatables allows you to add sorting, paging, filtering, limiting, and more to any html table.  You can also use it to add via json or ajax, but in this case you'll want to lean on the former.  Theming is possible via ThemeRoller, which makes your table easy to style and instantly (even user-end) restyle-able.

There is a [method to do a fixed-header slider](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html).  However, from a UI and usability standpoint the paging is going to be a better solution.